# Please explain how css rotate3d works

Tags: css

I have an image to which I applied `transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,90deg)` where each of the parameters represents X,Y, and Z axises respectively (according to CSS).
The image is supposed to disappear from the view it is displayed skewed.

Let's break it down:
`rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg)` will hide the image because if your rotate the image 90degrees on X axis then the image will lie flat on X axis. This part works. You can test it in the browser.
Let's add Y axis: `rotate3d(1,1,0,90deg)` and the image is still not shown which is correct. It doesn't matter now to which degree you rotate the image on Y axis - we still don't see the image.
When I add the third axis Z - `rotate3d(1,1,1,90deg)` the image is displayed skewed. Why? It's is supposed to rotate the invisible image 90degrees which should result in invisible image))))

So how does CSS rotate3d work? Does anyone know? I haven't found the answer on the Internet.

Comment: i also don;t know, but according to your description, i would assume that the 3 values you set to 1 define the rotation axis, and around this axis the image is rotated by 90 degree, and thus it makes sense that it does not disappear.

Comment: One thing you should try - open up your developer tools and set the `transition` property of your images, and then start changing around the values of x, y & z. That should help illustrate what is going on

Comment: That's what I did. Trying to rotate around X axis, then around Y, and then around Z. I did it with my coworker too. We don't know what's going on.

Comment: If you rotate the image degree by degree the image rotates in all directions.

Comment: If you rotate the image degree by degree the image doesn't rotate around some axis nor it respects the individual values.

Answer (score 1):

**hoijui**, you were right, those numbers make up an axis from the center of my image to the 3d coordinate (1,1,1). But the image **doesn't** rotate around axis - **axis rotates the image**! :) Almost like Galileo's discovery :)

So, to understand rotate3d just take a square piece of paper, puncture it with a tooth pick which is going to be your axis. Position the paper and a toothpick in front of your eyes (not too close or you will puncture your eye!). Now tilt the toothpick tip (which is facing you) to the right bottom corner of the paper (bottom is because in CSS `rotate3d` the Y is directed down). Z depends on how long your toothpick is. If your toothpick is the same length as width of your paper than the coordinate will be(1,1,1) which I was using for the experiment. Now start rolling the toothpick in your hands. You will see exactly the same effect that you will see on the screen if you try to manually increase the angle in firebug or developer tools.